# number of k-ary tree from pre-order and post-order traversals

Tags: math, tree, combinatorics

Suppose pre-order and post-order traversals and k are given. How many k-ary trees are there with these traversals?

An k-ary tree is a rooted tree for which each vertex has at most k children.

Comment: Why are traversals relevant for the number of trees?

Comment: @Henry : you know , you cant construct a tree from pre-order and post-order traversals uniquely, but I wanna know hom many trees have these traversals .

Comment: can you give an example were two different trees have the same pre- AND post-order traversal?

Comment: @Henry : see this link :http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the particular traversal pair.  For instance

```
pre-order:  a b c
post-order: b c a
```

describes only one possible tree (the fewest possible, unless you include inconsistent traversal pairs).  On the other hand:

```
pre-order:  a b c
post-order: c b a
```

describes 2^(3-1) = 4 trees (the most possible amongst all scenarios where the traversals have 3 nodes and k can be anything), namely the 4 3-node lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of possible binary trees having Pre-order and Post-order traversals, you should first draw one possible tree. then count the number of nodes with only one child. The total number of possible trees would be : 2^(Number of single-child nodes)

as an example:
pre: adbefgchij
post: dgfebijhca

i draw one tree that has 3 single-child nodes. So , the number of possible trees is 8.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the corresponding range of sub-tree by **DFS**, and get the amount of sub-tree, then solve it through combination of the sub-trees.

```
const int maxn = 30;
int C[maxn][maxn];
char pre[maxn],post[maxn];
int n,m;

void prepare()
{
    memset(C,0,sizeof(C));
    for(int i=0;i<maxn;i++)
    {
        C[i][0] = 1;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<maxn;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}

int dfs(int rs,int rt,int os,int ot)
{
    if(rs == rt) return 1;
    int son = 0,res = 1;
    int l = rs + 1,r = os;
    while(l <= rt)
    {
        while(r < ot)
        {
            if(pre[l] == post[r])
            {
                son++;
                break;
            }
            r++;
        }
        res *= dfs(l , l + r - os , os , r);
        l += r - os + 1;
        rs = l - 1;
        os = ++r;
    }
    return res * C[m][son];
}

int main()
{
    prepare();
    while(scanf("%d",&m) && m)
    {
        scanf("%s %s",pre,post);
        n = strlen(pre);
        printf("%d\n",dfs(0,n-1,0,n-1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```